# Python: decorating simple recursive function

Tags: python, function, recursion, decorator

I wanted to practice recursive and decorators and try to do this simple function but it doesn't work:

```
 def dec(func):

     def wrapper(number):
         print("Recursive count:")
         rec_cou(number)

     return wrapper

 @dec
 def rec_cou(number):
     """ Count from 0 to a given number from 50 and up """

     if number == 0:
         print(number)
         return number
     num = rec_cou(number - 1)
     print(num + 1)
     return num + 1

 rec_cou(53)
```

The recursive function alone works well, but when i add the decorator generates error: maximun recursion depth exceeded

Comment: ....out of curiosity, why are you using a decorator at all here?

Comment: @KyleStrand Just wanted to print only one time the text "Recursive count:" each time i call rec_cou. I know how to do it now creating a new attribute in the decorator. But would be good to know a more simple way.

Comment: I would say that a decorator is simply not the right language construct for that. Just move the "first time" flag inside the recursive function.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with first time flag.

Comment: It's the flag indicating whether the function is being called for the first time (i.e. prior to the recursive descent). In Joel's answer, it's the member `wrapper.initial`.

Comment: I would have to create another funcion inside the recursive function to do that?

Comment: What? No. Why would you need to create another function? I guess I'll write up a new answer to demonstrate what I'm saying, since comment formatting doesn't really work for Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the maximum recursion depth problem, call the function passed into the decorator (`func`) rather than `rec_cou` and return the value of the function call. That is, on line 5, replace `rec_cou(number)` with `return func(number)`.

Edit:

```
def decorate(function):
    def wrapper(parameter):
        if wrapper.initial:
            print("Recursive count:")
            wrapper.initial = False
        result = function(parameter)
        wrapper.initial = True
        return result

    wrapper.initial = True
    return wrapper

@decorate
def count(number):
    """ Prints integers on the interval [0, number] """
    if number:
        count(number - 1)
    print(number)

count(53)
```

Without decorator:

```
def count(number):
    """ Prints integers on the interval [0, number] """
    if number:
        count(number - 1)
    else:
        print("Recursive count:")
    print(number)

count(53)
```

Comment: Exactly, that was my mistake. But i wanted that the text "Recursive count:" was showed only one time when the function is called. And this way "Recursive count:" is printed 53 times.

Comment: @DmitryIvanov I see. I'll add some code that does that.

Comment: Great solution. Is there other way more simple to do the same, printing that text only one time when the function is called. Maybe without a decorator?

Comment: @DmitryIvanov Yes. I added another example.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your decorator:

1. You try to call the *decorated* function, effectively invoking the wrapper function again inside the decorator, thus you have an infinite recursive loop; call the original function `func` instead.
2. To the outside, the decorated function should behave just like the original function, particularly it should return its result; otherwise you will get type errors for trying to add numbers and `None`

Also, currently your decorator is not counting anything... try this:

```
def dec(func):
    func.count = 0          # give each decorated function its own counter
    def wrapper(number):
        print("Recursive count: %d" % func.count)
        func.count += 1     # increase counter
        return func(number) # call original function 'func' and return result
    return wrapper
```

---

*Update:* From your comments, it seems I misunderstood what your decorator is supposed to do, and you misunderstood how decorators work. The decorator is not called once when you first call the function, but it *replaces* the function with the one defined within the decorator. In other words,

```
@dec
def foo(...):
    ...
```

is equivalent to

```
def foo(...):
   ...
foo = dec(foo)
```

I.e. the decorator in invoked exactly once when the function is decorated, and the function constructed in the decorator is called each time the original function is called, replacing it. If you want to print only once, either use the decorator from the other answer, or rather use no decorator at all: Just create a wrapper that prints and then calls the function. This is not unusual for providing an 'entry point' to recursive functions.

```
def print_and_run(number):
    print("Recursive count:")
    rec_cou(number)
```

BTW, this is the decorator that I usually use to visualize recursive calls:

```
def trace(f):
    trace.depth = 0
    def _f(*args, **kwargs):
        print "  " * trace.depth, ">", f.__name__, args, kwargs
        trace.depth += 1
        res = f(*args, **kwargs)
        trace.depth -= 1
        print "  " * trace.depth, "<", res
        return res
    return _f
```

Comment: In addition, it's probably a good idea to move the `print(number)` line above the recursive call.  Otherwise you get all 53 "Recursive count:" outputs followed by all 53 numbers, instead of each number going with each printing of "Recursive count:".

Comment: @BrenBarn I tried that and it didn't work. I still have 53 "Recursive count". I just wanted the decorator to print that text one time each time i call the function. Not when the decorator is applied. Still don't know hot to do that. With your modification the change is that the 0 is not printed.

Comment: @DmitryIvanov See my update. It seems there have been some misunderstandings, and what you need might not be a decorator at all.

Comment: Create a new wrapper looks more simple, but i have to call that wrapper. I want to call the recursive function directly and that the text is printed only one time. Thanks for the explanation of decorators and the examples. I have a hard time understanding them.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is for the function `rec_cou` to print something before its recursive descent, just modify *that function* and don't bother with decorators.

```
def rec_cou(number, internal_call=False):
     """ Count from 0 to a given number from 50 and up """
     if not internal_call:
         print "Now performing recursive count, starting with %d" % number
     if number == 0:
         return number
     num = rec_cou(number - 1, internal_call=True)
     return num + 1
```

As I mentioned in my comments, all I've done is take the idea behind Joel's answer (which was to add a variable--which I called a "flag"--indicating whether the function is being called externally or as part of the recursion) and moved the flag variable (which I've called `internal_call`, whereas Joel called it `initial`) inside the function itself.

---

Additionally, I'm not sure what all this `num` business is about. Note that:

- For the `0` case, `rec_cou` returns 0.
- For `number > 0`, `num` is set to the value returned by `rec_cou(number-1)`, then `1+num` is returned.

For example, in the case of `rec_cou(1)`, `num` is set to `rec_cou(0)`, which is `0`, then `0 + 1` is returned, which is `1`. Similarly, for `rec_cou(2)`, one more than the value of `rec_cou(1)` is returned, so `2` is returned.

In short, for every natural number, `rec_cou(number)` returns the value of the input number. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but what you've got is an identity function, which seems unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: Excelent, i like this. Adding a new parameter set to False. I wanted this, also that all the numbers are printed, that's why i add print. It's really not necesary what i did, creating a variable num and then return num + 1, its better not use any variable, like joel example.